# Calculating intensity for an RGB Color

Tags: arrays, c, function, struct, rgb

i would like to ask how i can calculate my variable y for an RGB color intensity.

These r,g,b letters in my RGB_Trypel **struct** are representing each array element for the arrays rot, gelb, gruen, weiss, schwarz. So i need here to multiply these r,g,b array elements with the shown numbers in my y variable.

i would really be glad for some help.

```
#define CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

struct RGB_Trypel
    {
        
    unsigned char r, g, b; // speichert Werte nur bis 255 und positive Werte

    };




int main(void)
{
    
    struct RGB_Trypel rot = { 255,0,0 }, gelb = { 255,255,0 }, gruen = { 0,255,0 };

    const  struct RGB_Trypel weiss = { 255,255,255 };
    const  struct RGB_Trypel schwarz = { 0,0,0 };

    struct RGB_Trypel fafeld[5] = { rot, gelb, gruen, weiss, schwarz };
    int n = 5;
    
    unsigned char intensiteat(struct RGB_Trypel t);
    {
        int = y;
        

        y = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b;
    }
    


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

        printf("(%3d,%3d,%3d): \t intensiteat(%d) \n",fafeld[i].r, fafeld[i].g, fafeld[i].b, intensiteat(fafeld[i]);


    }


    return 0;
}
```

I am not really sure how i can put my struct array element into a function and let it multiply following numbers in my y variable.

Comment: Do you need to represent the intensity as an `unsigned char`, an `int` or a `double`? If of integral type, would a triplet like { 255, 255, 254 } be considered having an intensity of 254 or 255?

Answer (score 1):

Your big problem here is that this

```
 unsigned char intensiteat(struct RGB_Trypel t);
{
    int = y;
    

    y = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b;
}
```

looks like an attempt to define a function inside another function. This wont work. Move it to be before main. Like this:

```
 unsigned char intensiteat(struct RGB_Trypel t)
{
    int = y;
    

    y = 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b;
}


 int main(void)
 {
```

second, to refer to fields of a struct inside that function do this:

```
 unsigned char intensiteat(struct RGB_Trypel t)
{
    int = y;
    

    y = 0.299 * t.r + 0.587 * t.g + 0.114 * t.bb;
}
```

you have multiple other errors, but this will get you started

BTW you missed an _ of the front the that define. Should be:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
```

Comment: Some other errors are a) remove `;` after function definition, b) add the struct prefix `t.` and c) `int = y;` should be `int y;` and d) missing `)` after `printf`.

Comment: OP might also need the Y conversion to be `double y = 0.299 * t.r + 0.587 * t.g + 0.114 * t.b; if(y > 255) return 255; return (unsigned char)round(y);`

Comment: @WeatherVane - not to mention `int = y` - :).

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thank you that was helpful. 

I was also just shaking my head why i would put my function inside my main function, although i know that it has to be outside of main. 

beside other few dumbs errors. Thankyou :)